# solving an equation from trigonometry

Tags: trigonometry

I am trying to solve the following trigonometric equation: $$\frac{\cot\theta+\csc\theta}{\tan\theta+\sec\theta}=\cot(\pi/4+\theta/2)\cot \theta/2$$ but unfortunately, after giving a lot of effort I am unable to solve the problem, I think I am missing some obvious steps so the problem is getting messed up but I wasn't able to point out my fault, I also tried to solve it by starting from RHS but I also failed in there.

I will be very much grateful if someone helps me.

Comment: Have you tried converting everything into $ \sin \theta, \cos \theta$ and simplified the expression?

Comment: yes sir I do, primarily tried to use submultiple angle formula but I wasn't able to prove the result.

Comment: Can you show what you get when converting into sin, cos, expanding the multiple angle, and then simplifying?

Comment: Actually I wished to write the whole thing I found after reading the guideline but  actually as a high school student I am not quite good at latex. ok, after computing a bit I easily found $cot(\theta/2)$ but the remaining expression I get was $\frac{cos\theta}{sin\theta+1}$ from there I didn't able to make any progress.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{\cot \theta+\csc \theta}{\tan \theta+ \sec \theta}= \frac{1+\cos \theta}{1+\sin \theta}~\frac{\cos \theta}{\sin \theta}$$ $$=\frac{2\cos^2(\theta/2)}{[\sin(\theta/2)+\cos(\theta/2)]^2}\frac{\cos^2(\theta/2)-\sin^2(\theta/2)}{2\sin(\theta/2) \cos(\theta/2)}=\cot(\theta/2) \frac{\cos (\theta/2)-\sin(\theta/2)}{\cos (\theta/2)+\sin(\theta/2)}$$
$$=\cot(\theta/2) \frac{1-\tan(\theta/2)}{1+\tan(\theta/2)}=\cot(\theta/2) \tan(\pi/4-\theta/2)=\cot(\theta/2) \cot(\pi/4+\theta/2).$$
Use $\tan(\pi/2-z)=\cot z$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $c=\cot\dfrac\theta2$

Use [Weierstrass substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_substitution#The_substitution)

$$\tan\theta=\cdots=\dfrac{2c}{c^2-1}$$

$$\sin\theta=\cdots=\dfrac{2c}{c^2+1}$$

$$\cos\theta=\cdots=\dfrac{c^2-1}{c^2+1}$$

If $c\ne0,$

LHS  $=\dfrac{\dfrac{c^2-1}{2c}+\dfrac{c^2+1}{2c}}{\dfrac{2c}{c^2-1}+\dfrac{c^2+1}{c^2-1}}=\dfrac{c(c^2-1)}{(c+1)^2}=c\cdot\dfrac{c-1}{c+1}$ if $c+1\ne0$

Finally use [Prove that $\cot(A+B)=\frac{\cot A\cot B-1}{\cot A+\cot B}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/439503/prove-that-cotab-frac-cot-a-cot-b-1-cot-a-cot-b)